# Set the name of an animation in collada to be used by AssImp

Tags: c++, assets, assimp, collada

I am using the collada file format to contain my model and animation but when I use AssImp to load the file the name will be empty for the animation. Where is the name for animation set on the collada file format? The documentation seems to have pointed me to library_animations but I tried setting "name" and "id", but both did not end up setting the animation name.

To get the animation name I am simply doing

```
        aiAnimation* animation = mAIScene->mAnimations[i];
        auto test = animation->mName;
```

Comment: What are you using to export the file? The problem might be the exporter.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably the exporter.
According to [official docs](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/lib_html/structai_animation.html#a8de0bb4f23cfd3b395483f125f3d5f93):

> **aiString aiAnimation::mName**
>
> The name of the animation.
>
> If the modeling package this data was exported from does support only
>   a single animation channel, this name is usually empty (length is
>   zero).

Try to find one which *does* support multiple animations channel.